# kdb: Tabulation by 2 keys, including combos with 0 counts

Tags: kdb

When one does something like `select Count:count i by Id,sym from T` we will of course get a simple keyed table much like the following:

```
t1:`Id`sym xkey ([]Id:`A`A`B`B;sym:`sym1`sym2`sym2`sym3;Count:3 4 8 8)
```

Note though that there is no entry with `` (Id=`A, sym=`sym3) `` or `` (Id=`b,sym=`sym2) ``.  In my tabulation, I would like to include these null combos, where the counts are filled in with 0s.  The ouput should look something like this:

```
t2:`Id`sym xkey([]Id:`A`A`A`B`B`B;sym:`sym1`sym2`sym3`sym1`sym2`sym3;Count:3 4 0 0 8 8)
```

Cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this:

```
q)0^((select distinct Id from t1) cross select distinct sym from t1)#t1
Id sym | Count
-------| -----
A  sym1| 3
A  sym2| 4
A  sym3| 0
B  sym1| 0
B  sym2| 8
B  sym3| 8
```

or (essentially the same thing)

```
q)0^2!lj[;t1] (select distinct Id from t1) cross select distinct sym from t1
Id sym | Count
-------| -----
A  sym1| 3
A  sym2| 4
A  sym3| 0
B  sym1| 0
B  sym2| 8
B  sym3| 8
```

Note - the "zero fill" only works here if Count is the only unkeyed column. Otherwise you'd have to do an update 0^Count from table

Answer (score 1):

The same approach as @terrylynch but just making it slightly more general in case your t1 has multiple key columns

```
q)t:([]id:10?3; sym:10?`a`b`c; val:10?1.)
q)k xasc 0^(flip k!flip (cross) . distinct each t k:keys tg)#tg:select ct:count i by id, sym from t
id sym| ct
------| --
0  a  | 0 
0  b  | 1 
0  c  | 2 
1  a  | 1 
1  b  | 2 
1  c  | 0 
2  a  | 1 
2  b  | 1 
2  c  | 2
```